# Newton Mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

I am confused about this question, what does it mean?

A particle has a mass of $2\ \mathrm{kg}$ and a force $$F = 24t^2 i + ( 36t - 6 ) j - 12tk$$ acting on it. At the time $t = 0$ the particle is at position $r = 3i - j + 4k$ and has initial velocity $v=6i+15j-8t$. Look for speed as a function of $t$ and position at every time.

Comment: Break things up into $i,j,k$ by themselves, and solve the 1-D problem in each case.

Comment: can you explain it step by step,please, because i really confused

Comment: First of all how can you subtract a scalar from a vector?$v=

Comment: i know that but i don't know how to use that and my tecaher didn't give me a example so i don't know what the first step i can do

Comment: sathyaram-ganapathy i don't know what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean "what does it mean?" It seems to me that it's pretty clear what the question wants, as given in the last sentence...

Comment: Start with $F(t)$, you can use that to solve for $a(t)$.  When you have $a(t)$, you can solve for $v(t)$, and when you have $v(t)$, you can solve for $x(t)$.

Comment: can you give me what parts to intergate in equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to answer your question for you, as that would deprive you from learning the material. I can clear up a few things for you though.

The mass is $2kg$

The Force is given as three component vectors in the x, y, z direction ($i,j,k$)

It gives you its velocity is three component vectors as well. You are given Force, Velocity($V_i$), Mass, and position. It asks for you to find $V_f (t)$

Use newtons second law and calculus to solve for $V_f$.

I'll do one of the components for you to get an idea of what you are looking for. Doing the entire problem is just time consuming.

As you probably already know any vector is the sum of all component vectors: $\overrightarrow {F_i} = \overrightarrow {F_x}+\overrightarrow {F_y}+\overrightarrow {F_z}$

Lets just look at the X-component for all given information.
You are dealing, like I said, with Force, Mass, $V_o$, and position ($\Delta S$)

$F_x = 24t^2N$

$\Delta S_x = 3m$

$V_{x}= 6 ms^{-1}$

$m=2kg$

If you are lost at this point, go look at the original information you provided to see where I found the numbers above.

Now it asks you to provide a function of both Velocity and Position with respect to time, in laymans terms its asking you to find $V_f(t)$ and $\Delta S (t)$. We are going to do this just for the X- component vector (you still need to do it for Y and Z which I won't do on here).

So with the knowns that you have, you can find the $V_f$ by using newtons second law:

$$
a={F \over m}
$$

Then use integral calculus to find Velocity as a function of time:

$$
{d v \over d t } = {F_x \over m} 
$$

Rearrange equation and simplify
$$
{dv } = {24t^2 \over m} d t
$$

$$
\int_{V_o}^{V_f} {dv} = {1 \over m} \int_{t_o}^{t_f} {{24t^2} dt}
$$

$$
V_f - V_o = {1 \over m} \mid_{t_o}^{t_f} 8t_f^3 -8t_o^3
$$

$$
V_{fx}(t)= {8 \Delta t^3 \over m} +V_{ox}
$$
Plugging in known values you get.
$$
V_{fx}(t)=4t^3 +6 
$$

Now this is where I leave you to figure out the rest for yourself, because now you have to take what you are given and find a function of position in respect to time, and not only that but now you are going to have to find a function for both velocity and position for the remaining vector components of Y and Z

Hope this helps.

** Hint to easily find position from the velocity formula use calculus **

Comment: i'm really begginer for that,can you give me please some example like that?

Comment: @jhonlubis i explained more in detail in my edit above

Comment: Someone has twice now ([one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/104629), [two](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/104630)) suggested an edit (because they do not have sufficient rep to comment) stating *This answer is wrong, the acceleration is not constant!*. Thought you might want to address that.

Comment: I stand corrected. I will make the edit now. Thank you for bringing that up.

Comment: @jhonlubis might want to read a overhaul of the original post